# Count how many posts user have

Tags: python, django

I've got a little problem: I want to count how many posts a specific user has.
I already tried these things.

Here is view.py:

```
def home(request):
    numb = Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()
```

here is  models.py

```
 class Post(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

Is there anything I need to write here more ?
After it I am getting error message user is undefined.

Comment: the user that is logged in is `request.user`, but if you need another one, you of course need to specify the user. Furthermore here you do not return a HTTP response, so it will - if the error is fixed - complain that your view returned `None`. You thus need to generate a response (for example a JSON response, or by rendering a template).

Answer (score 0):

you can get logged in user by:

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated(): #check if user is logged in
        user = request.user
        numb = Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()
    else:
        pass #return some errors like: login first
```

Comment: its working but when you are logged in but i want if someone who is not logged in  he could see which person have how much posts

Answer (score 0):

```
def home(request):
  user=request.user
  numb_post_by_user = Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()
  allpost=Post.objects.all().count()
```